# How to restrict search result to one country in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an application, in Ionic, where you can search for different addresses (to plan a trip). My problem is that I want to restrict the search results to one country, but I can't figure out how to do so.

This is how I initialize the map:

```
 initMap() {
    var point = { lat: 55.6761, lng: 12.5683 };
    let divMap = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('map'));
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(divMap, {
      center: point,
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      draggable: true,
      zoomControl: true,
    });
  }
```

This is how I search for addresses:

```
getItems(ev: any, startEnd: string) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initRoutes();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    //if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    //Returns both the start and end value of address to the (ionInput)
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      val = val.trim();
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        var searchResult = true;
        if (item.RouteEndAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
          || item.RouteStartAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) return true;
        val.split(" ").forEach(element => {
          if (!(item.RouteEndAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(element.toLowerCase()) > -1
            || item.RouteStartAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(element.toLowerCase()) > -1)) searchResult = false;
        });
        return searchResult;
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: @maninak How do I use that in mine?